# Retriving old values with many-to-many association

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I usually use `old` function at my view files to retrieve old values when editing an entity. For example:

```
    {!! Form::model($shop, [
        'action' => ['ShopController@update', $shop->id], 
        'method' => 'patch']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', old('name')) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn')) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This works fine to simple fields, but this does not seem to work with 'many to many' (belongsToMany) relations.
Supposing that a relation of this kind results in an array of objects, how can I retrieve them in the view without generating a lot of code?

I was thinking something like this, in a multiselect, for a shop that has a many-to-many relation with products:

```
{!! Form::select('products[]', $allProducts, old('products[]')) !!}
```

This does not seem to work because there are no `products` in the model, but through a relation model like: `ShopProduct`.

Anyone know a clever way to do this?

Comment: for many to many you can retrieve values with a foreach if i understand right what do you want to do

Comment: Actually, this is what I don't want to do. I'm already retrieving the values with a foreach and sending them to the view through an array. But I found this very 'complicated'. So I was wondering if Laravel provides a better aproach, like Rails, for example.

Comment: I only know two way to do it. The one that you did and the Eager Loading that you can see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading. I don't know about ruby on rails  :/